# Clear logs in Developer Console

Tags: developer-console

How do I clear the logs in the Developer Console?

Can't find it in the [logs documentation on Salesforce](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_debugging_system_log_console.htm) nor googling. I know it should be simple but can't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

The above diagram shows how to clear the logs in developer console

Answer (score 3):

In the Developer Console, on the Logs tab, use "Debug | Clear | Log Panel" to do this.  More details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tab_browser_logs.htm&language=en_US#topic-title)

You can also do this under Setup.  Go to "Monitor | Logs | Debug Logs", and there's a "delete all" button.

Comment: Note that those two are not the same. Hitting clear in the developer console does not delete the logs, but just hides all old ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataLoader to export and mass delete debug logs if you have a lot - just use query SELECT Id FROM ApexLog